# Is Php 'POST' case insensitive?

Tags: php, post

I followed a tutorial in which the author had this in his code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post'){

echo 'something';

}
```

I had always used 'POST' instead of 'post' for these kinds of things. For me 'something' was not getting echoed when in fact there was a POST data submitted to the page. I changed 'post' to 'POST' and it worked!

Now I thought POST was case insensitive, and no body in the comments mentioned that they were having the same problem. So what was wrong here? Why was it not working with 'post'

Also the in the form that submitted data to this page had this: method='post'

Please let me know about this. Thank you.

Comment: `if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'post')` use instead

Comment: @metal_fan That'll make sure it's done right; good comment, should've implemented it as an answer. Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are, as per [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (emphasis mine):

> 5.1.1 Method
>    The [HTTP] Method  token indicates the method to be performed on the resource identified by the Request-URI. **The method is case-sensitive**.

Since this information is passed to PHP by whatever container it's running from  (mod_php, etc.), the method would have to be uppercase in order for it to be accepted.

Comment: +1, but I used `method="POST"` and `method="post"` and PHP responses with `POST` for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. Is this a server sided action, or does the browser make method types automatically upper-cased?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings and that is case sensitive.

So you need to compare with 'POST'

Comment: @SameerZahid Do you have a link to the tutorial? Maybe there's something else going on there.